# Java threaded Random.nextLong() returning the same number

Tags: java, multithreading, random, thread-safety

I'm using an OAuth library that calls new Random().nextLong() to generate nonces, however it generates the same nonce on asynchronous calls. I've narrowed it down to threading Random.nextLong() to returning the same exact number every so often.

Does anyone know if this is a known limitation of Java? If so, does anyone know of a thread safe operation?

EDIT: I'm using Java 1.6

EDIT: This is a small program I made to test out what was going on in my larger app. I ran this several times and more often that it should, it was coming up with the same random number when the time was the same. Please excuse my quick programming.

```
public class ThreadedRandom {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    new ThreadedRandom().run();
}

private RandomNumberGenerator _generator;

public ThreadedRandom()
{
    _generator = new RandomNumberGenerator();
}

public void run()
{
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {
            System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis()+"\t"+_generator.gen());
        }
    };

    Thread t1, t2;

    t1 = new Thread(r);
    t2 = new Thread(r);

    t1.start();
    t2.start();
}

private class RandomNumberGenerator {

    Random random;
    public RandomNumberGenerator()
    {
        random = new Random();
    }

    public Long gen() {
        return new Random().nextLong();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: See SecureRandom - http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html

Comment: This really shouldn't happen, especially it shouldn't happen often, as it uses System.nanoTime and a volatile seedUniquifier.

Comment: What version of Java are you using to run your code?

Comment: @Jigar - I added my test code

Comment: Your field RandomNumberGenerator.random gets never used, watch for compiler warnings. With my Java 1.6 it works fine, the times are the same but the longs differ.

Comment: @maaartinus Sorry I was playing around with doing new Random() for each or having a single Random. With the current code and 10 runs, I had 50% of the runs (with same currentTimeMillis) be the same "random" longs. Runs 1, 2, 4, 6, 8 were different and 3, 5, 7, 9, 10 were the same... (I removed the runs that were reporting different currentTimeMillis)

Comment: You say, you're using Java 1.6? Then this must be a bug. Report System.nanoTime() as it gets used in the ctor. As a solution: use a single instance of Random. Or, since it seems to be seriously broken, take SecureRandom. Actually: Do the nonces have to be random? Wouldn't a counter (AtomicLong) do? Wouldn't it be more save? If not, are you aware, that numbers produced by Random are quite predictable. Doesn't predictability ruin the security in your case?

Answer (score 4):

You might not want to be creating a new instance of Random each time. Rather have a global one.

Comment: with new Object each time also this is not expected.

Comment: @org, it is expected wit ha new Random every time.  Because Random is seeded with the current millisecond, if two Randoms are created within the same millisecond, their numbers will be the same.

Comment: WRONG. Random in the current version is seeded via `++seedUniquifier + System.nanoTime()`, which should generate a unique seed with very high probability.

Comment: @Justin: I don't think that's true.  There's a programatic way of changing the seed in that case.  I think it's as simple as counting instances of Random.

Comment: @Mark, true, you could count the instances, but `java.util.Random` does not do that.

Comment: @Justin: Yes it does is my point.  That's what seedUniquifier is doing, except instead of starting at 0 it starts at some arbitrary number.  But it gets incremented every time you create a `Random` without providing a seed.

Comment: @Justin I am curious about OP's issue,

Comment: @Justin: 1.5 is when it changed.  1.4 has the behaviour you describe.

Comment: @Mark, thanks.  I am super happy to have this new piece of info!

Comment: @Mark thanks ` public Random() { this(++seedUniquifier + System.nanoTime()); }`

Comment: I've modded this down as using SecureRandom as provided as solution by jtahlborn below is obviously the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

Random numbers are not truly random, they are "pseudo-random" and they require a "seed" value. If the same seed is used, the same sequence of pseudo-random values will be generated.

When you create a new instance of the Random class, you can either specify a seed yourself or let the system choose one for you. In Java, the default seed is the current system time in milliseconds, see:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#Random%28%29

If you create Random objects within the same millisecond, they will have the same sequence of values.

Normally you want to share a single Random object among all the different threads to avoid this kind of problem.

Comment: This isn't true for any Java version that's still in its service life.  [Java 5 made it so that this issue did not occur](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#Random()), and it was released over 6 years ago:

Comment: True, true, although I probably do spend more time with older Java versions than others. Am curious to know what version the OP is using.

Answer (score 1):

Although I'm not immediately familiar with the underlying implementation of `Random`, if I had to guess I would imagine that calling `new Random()` delegates to `new Random(System.currentTimeMillis())`. That gives a reasonably different `Random` sequence for Randoms instantiated at different times.

However, since you've mentioned asynchronous calls, it's possible your calls are both executing at essentially the same time. That means that when the threads invoke the library, they're both hitting the `new Random()` call at the same time, and the Randoms get identical seeds, so they will produce the same random sequence.

Comment: Again, it did back in Java 1.4 but that's ages ago.

Answer (score 1):

You should really be using SecureRandom since you are using this for something related to security.

Answer (score 0):

I thought Random was not thread safe, but it is.  You should only get Random producing the same number every 2^48 values.

As has been noted, Java 1.4 and previous had a bug where two Randoms could get the same seed. I suggest you use Java 6, or set the seed to be unique yourself.

You should also note that Random uses a 48-bit seed.  This means it will repeat after 2^48 values and produce only 2^48 unique long values.  If this is a problem for you, use a SecureRandom which is much more expensive, but will produce all possible long values.

Comment: Wrong, Random is thread-safe. Why do you think they're using volatile and AtomicLong for? You're right about the 48-bit seed.

Comment: Does the 48-bit seed really mean that it will only generate 2^48 unique long values, or simply 2^48 unique *sequences*?  Clearly the set of possible first numbers could only number 2^48.  But that doesn't mean that the numbers that can't be the first number couldn't appear at some point later in the sequence...

Comment: As an example, imagine a naive "random" generated that was seeded with either a 1 or a 0, with an algorithm of `number = first ? seed : number + 1`.  This would still visit every number despite having a 1-bit seed.  It's just each *individual* invocation would only have `2^1` possible values.