# Random class acting odd?

Tags: java, random

In this code:

```
Random random = new Random(441287210);
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    System.out.print(random.nextInt(10)+" ");
}
```

The output is `1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1`, every time.

Why is this? Isn't `Random` supposed to be... well... random? I thought that the `Random` class use `System.nanoTime`, so the output should be generally random. Can someone please explain?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797849/java-threaded-random-nextlong-returning-the-same-number

Comment: [Maybe it is random!](http://search.dilbert.com/comic/Random%20Number%20Generator)

Comment: @JeremyD Not really-that question creates a new random object every time.

Comment: "Any one who considers arithmetical methods of producing random digits is, of course, in a state of sin." - John von Neumann

Comment: @climbage If you don look at the question oly but the second answer, it is the correct answer, the same as proposed here :)

Comment: You took the wrong seed, use -45134723714 instead!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The values generated by `Random` class are **pseudo-random**: they are created using a deterministic algorithm, based on seed value. Typically (if you use parameterless constructor, for example) the seed is initialized using current time, which is obviously a unique value. Hence a unique, 'random' sequence is generated.

Here you are using a constant seed value which doesn't change between executions of your code. Therefore you always get the same sequence. It just happens that this sequence is `1 1 1 1 1 1 ...` for this particular seed.

Comment: Excluding classes/methods that draw entropy from sources like `/dev/random`, what random generator *isn't* pseudo-random?

Comment: None. I just wanted to clear possible confusion regarding the use of "random" word here. Normally people know they are referring to pseudo-random (i.e. deterministically computed) numbers but here OP seemed to have expected true (non-deterministic) randomness.

Answer (score 20):

Let it print a couple more, the first 100 are

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 4 7 2 2 6 0 3 0 2 8 4 1 6 0 0 0 2 8 2 9 8 9 2 5 2 1 1 4 5 3 4 1 4 1
8 7 6 6 0 6 5 0 4 5 5 6 0 8 3 8 9 7 4 0 9 9 7 7 9 3 9 6 4 5 0 6 3 7 4 9 8 7 6 2 8 9 8 4 4
8 4 9 0 1 6 9 6 1 5
```

which looks okay.

Every good (pseudo) random sequence contains streaks of repeated numbers, this one begins with one.

Comment: nathan, I'd be horrified if online Poker used a crappy LCG.

Comment: And, they can't afford to be that blunt, there's too much money to earn without rigging.

Comment: they make it look good, but they don't account for all possibilities. they make sure that all the possibilities that create action exist but leave out some of the more mundane decks that exist in real life creating more excitement and action and giving worse players a better chance.

Comment: @nathanhayfield Every game of chance used in gambling is rigged, by design, to win money for the house in the long term, even if the house plays fair. The massive scale at which online casinos operate (compared to brick-and-mortar casinos) pretty much guarantees consistent profits.

Comment: People have done rigorous statistical analysis of millions of hands of online poker and never found any evidence to suggest that they were doing anything other than truly random shuffling. In addition, there are three facts here: 1. there is very little incentive to rig hands, 2. there is a huge dis-incentive if it was found out that they were, and 3. it would be easy for someone to prove that it was rigged if it were. Simply put, online poker companies definitely do not do anything of the sort.

Answer (score 5):

There's nothing to say that a sequence of 10 `1`s in a row is not possible.  Whoever gave you the seed value `441287210` just happens to have found such a value that results in starting with 10 `1`s in a row.  If you continue calling `nextInt()` (i.e. more than 10 times) you will see random values.  It should be possible to find other seed values that will result in other "apparently non-random" sequences.

Comment: In fact, seeing as there are `1.8e19` possible values for `long`, and thus sequences that `Random` can produce, there's a good chance that for every possible sequence of 10 numbers a seed exists that will make `Random` generate them as the first ten results for `nextInt(10)`. (An exercise left to a reader better at stats/probability than me would be determining the actual probability of this. Or rather, of `1.8e19` truly random picks of 10 digits ending up having picked all possible sequences of 10 digits.)

Answer (score 3):

Random is a [linear congruential generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator); i.e. it is based on a formula of the form:

```
N <- (N * C1 + C2) % M
```

where C1, C2 and M are constants.

One of the properties of this class of generator is that has high auto-correlation.  Indeed, if you plot successive numbers you can see clear stripping patterns in the numbers.

Your test program has effectively taken 10 successive numbers from the underlying generator, calculated their value modulo 10 ... and found that they are all the same.  Effectively, the modulo 10 is "resonating" with the natural periodicity of the generator ... over a short period of time.

This is one of the downsides of using a PRNG with high auto-correlation.  In layman's terms ... it is "not very random" ... and you can get into trouble if you use it in a situation where randomness is critical.

---

Notes:

- Random is not a random number generator.  It is a *pseudo-random* number generator.  That means that if you know the initial state, the numbers generated are entirely predictable.
- Using a true random seed for Random doesn't really help.  It just makes the problem harder to reproduce.
- There are likely to be other seeds for Random that will give you similar patterns with this particular test.
- From a purely mathematical standpoint, ten ones is no more or less "random" than any other sequence of ten numbers.  But from a mathematical perspective, `Random` is not random at all.  In fact, it is totally predictable once you have figured out what the current value of `N` is.  The problem is the auto-correlation that is making the sequence appear intuitively non-random.
- If you want to avoid this kind of intuitive non-randomness, use SecureRandom which should either be a true random number source, or a generator of pseudo-random numbers that are much, much harder to predict.

Comment: " Effectively, the modulo 10 is "resonating" with the natural periodicity of the generator" Why this, usually prime numbers are used for the generator?

Answer (score 1):

If you use `for(int i=0;i<100;i++)`, the sequence outputted is "more random" again. The probability of a random sequence of ten `1`s in succession occuring might be small, but it's not impossible. (Insofar that given enough samples, any sequence is almost certain to occur.)

It's merely an interesting coincidence.

Comment: The probability of ten `1`s in a row is exactly the same as the probability of any other sequence.

Comment: @ChristofferHammarström Yes. It is, however, small in absolute terms. (I.e. if you were to pick seeds by hand it would take you a while to find precisely that starting sequences.)

Comment: Most probably that seed was not picked by hand.

Comment: @AlexWien Actually, I'd counter that it's exceedingly likely it was. The random number generator was seeded explicitly, with a number that produces a very recognizable sentence. How do you imagine the OP found this by chance? You can't access the seed of a `Random` instance without using reflection, so you're positing that someone is, as part of "normal" code, generating integers smaller than 10, and logging the sequence for some completely unrelated purpose, and inspecting the seed with every number generated to be able to reproduce this.

Comment: @AlexWien Basically, what I believe is is that any scenario in which what the OP found was discovered incidentally is pretty convoluted, i.e. unlikely, that it's more likely than not someone was looking for "interesting" `Random` seeds on purpose. A teacher trying to confuse / amuse his students, for instance.

Comment: One could write test code, that tries ,illions of seeds, and records that ones that produce the biggest sequence of identical repeating digits. A hand picked by seed, is less likelys than thenumber of software developpers in the world. So I am quite sure the seed was detected by brute force.

Comment: I was right: It was brute force: see here: http://insights.dice.com/2014/01/24/generating-random-numbers-javas-random-class/

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I meant "hand picked" metaphorically as "chosen deliberately" (to produce the observed effect), not literally.

Answer (score 0):

Random class uses **seed** to generate random number when you call nextInt() and is advised to be a long number, when you are creating random object, you are providing an int which is not sufficient enough for randomness.

Try to run the loop for 20 times, you will see randomness or remove seed or provide a very long seed value